# Subtract and Merging Images

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, image-processing, aforge

There are some component for Image processing operations like Subtraction, Merging, Get Difference and etc. .
Just Imagine, we have two images and wants to subtract them from each other.
And this operation makes a result image.
Now if i want to make picture two ,from adding picture 2 and result images ,i can't do this.
I Used AFroge.NET, openCV, magick and etc. components and the results are exactly same!
So I think i have problem in my algorithm...

How can i merge result image, and picture 1 to make picture two?

Thanks in Advanced.

**UPDATE**

This image is result of subtraction two images and save with JPEG : 
[image]

Size is 77 kb

Comment: What did you try? What does direct substraction (in cycles) result?

Comment: @Eddy_Em What do you mean by direct subtraction?

Comment: I mean substraction pixel by pixel, in cycle, without lots of libraries.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Yes i Tried it worked but the worst problem is the size of result image. size increas when i save it in JPEG image format. the complete pictures are smaller.

Comment: Can you give small working example of saving your image into jpeg? I think, you do something wrong on that step!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can post some code, together with the original pair of images used for subtraction.

Usually, direct subtraction alone will not give you the result. You have to get the difference between the two images, then calculate the magnitude of difference, and construct another image where you keep pixels of the first image if the magnitude is greater than 0 (or a small value if you want to compensate for noise).

There are some opencv functions that support background subtraction, but I haven't used them. You might want to check [this page](http://answers.opencv.org/question/7998/object-detection-using-background-subtraction/) for more information on that.

The JPEG files will be larger after subtraction, because there are more variations in the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clear. i am assuming you are saying you have image A and B and the difference of A - B stored in image D. then you want to reverse the process by adding B to D to recover A? is that correct?

if so, the most likely issue you have is that opencv etc will compute the absolute difference. hence your math wont work. to test make two images with known values and see if the difference image what you would expect. if not write your own subtraction algorithm and store result in an integer image or something that can support negative values.